# Cannot resolve symbol message for method from a class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created following method in SQLiteOpenHelper subclass:

```
public List<Data> getAll(){
        List<Data> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                int ID = cursor.getInt(0);
                int soundamp = cursor.getInt(1);
                String date = cursor.getString(2);
                String time = cursor.getString(3);
                double lat = cursor.getDouble(4);
                double lon = cursor.getDouble(5);
                Data newData = new Data(ID, soundamp, date, time, lat, lon);
                returnList.add(newData);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return returnList;
    }
```

But when I try to use this method in MainActivity on button click like this:

```
else if(v==viewAll){
            SQLite sql = new SQLite(MainActivity.this);
            List<Data> all = new sql.getAll();
        }
```

"getAll" gets highlighted red and I get the following message when I hover over it: Cannot resolve symbol 'getAll'.
Now I have tried Invalidating caches and restarting project but it didn't work, I have also tried Importing to a new project but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

What if you remove the `new` keyword when you call `getAll()`? You are not creating a new object there, your `all` list is just getting back the list your return from the method.

```java
else if(v==viewAll){
            SQLite sql = new SQLite(MainActivity.this);
            List<Data> all = new sql.getAll(); //remove new here
        }
```

Comment: This helped, thank you very much

Comment: @Dest420 no problem, you can click the answer checkmark if you want other users to see that this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `getAll()` method in a `SQLiteOpenHelper` class doesn't help if you want to call `getAll()` on an instance of the `SQLite` class.

Calling `getAll()` on an instance of the `SQLite` class is only valid if `SQLite` or one of its superclasses contains such a method (and most probably, `SQLiteOpenHelper` is not a superclass of `SQLite`).

EDIT:

I overlooked the `new` keyword that @net00 spotted, and of course that makes the attempted call unintellegible to the compiler. `new` must be followed by a classname, not a method call.

Comment: Valid argument, but i phrased my question wrong since my SQLite class extends SQLiteOpenHelper, thanks anyway, the problem was solved.